# Adding JS to HTML

Tags: javascript

**In the printFullName() function:**

1.Create a local variable also named fullName.

2.Assign the local variable the value, “Bill Smith”.

3.Add a list item to the HTML ordered list with the id of "outputList" with 
    the local fullName variable as the data.

**In the main function lab02localGlobal():**

1.Assign the name “Judy Green” to the global variable version of fullName.

2.Add a list item to the HTML ordered list with the id of "outputList" with 
    the global fullName variable as the data.

3.Call the printFullName() function.

**Should display like this: 
1. Judy Green
2. Bill Smith**

**However it keeps display this:
   Bill Smith
1. Bill Smith**

```
// global variables
var fullName;

fullName = "Judy Green";

function printFullName() {
"use strict";

  // declare variable
  var fullName;
  var output;

  // assign value to variable
  fullName = "Bill Smith";

  output = document.getElementById("outputList");
  fullName += "<li>" + fullName + "</li>";
  output.innerHTML = fullName;
}

function lab02localGlobal() {
"use strict";

   var output;

   output = document.getElementById("outputList");

   fullName = "<li>" + fullName + "</li>";
   output.innerHTML = fullName;

   printFullName();
}
```

Comment: can you make it clearer on what your question actually is?

Comment: You are replacing `fullName` in `printFullName` instead of appending to the `output`. You should probably call `output.innerHTML += ...`.

Comment: Consider @Makkes comment and Don't use `fullName += "<li>" + fullName + "</li>";`, It should be `fullName = "<li>" + fullName + "</li>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse you use `printFullName` set `fullName` value,But it will cover origin `fullName` became `Bill Smith`.You can try below code:

```js
// global variables
var fullName;

fullName = "Judy Green";

function printFullName() {
"use strict";

  // declare variable
  var fullName;
  var output;

  // assign value to variable
  fullName = "Bill Smith";

  output = document.getElementById("outputList");
  output.innerHTML += "<li>" + fullName + "</li>";
}

function lab02localGlobal() {
"use strict";

   var output;

   output = document.getElementById("outputList");

   fullName = "<li>" + fullName + "</li>";
   output.innerHTML = fullName;

   printFullName();
}

lab02localGlobal()
```

```html
<div id="outputList"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's beacuse you are overwriting your innerHTML in `printFullName()` function. Trying appending to what you have already added in `lab02localGlobal()`.

You can use `appendChild()` method. Refer https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/append-or-prepend-to-an-element-29/ for more details

Answer (score 1):

your function 'lab02localGlobal()' keeps replacing content of 'output' element, not adding/appending content to it.

You should change line:

```
output.innerHTML = fullName;
```

to:

```
output.append(fullName);
```